# Identification In The Photograph

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I have a question about the usage of the pattern "*identification in*" pattern [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Raising_the_Flag_on_Iwo_Jima):

> Three Marines depicted in the photograph, Harlon Block, Franklin Sousley, and Michael Strank, were killed in action over the next few days. The three surviving flag-raisers were Marines Rene Gagnon, Ira Hayes, and Navy Corpsman John Bradley. The latter three became celebrities after ***their identifications in the photograph***.

The act of identifying the flag-raisers was external to the photo and after the photo was taken.  So, is the "*in*" in the part "*identifications* ***in*** *the photograph*" wrong?  Would "*identifications* **from** *the photograph*", where "*from*" implies the source of information, be better?

Comment: The photograph wasn't used to identify them, they became celebrities posthumously after being identified as people in the famous photo.  I think the sentence could have been phrased better, but I don't think the meaning is unclear.

Comment: "their identifications in the photograph" sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Identification from X* mean *instance or action where X was used to determine identity.*  Whatever is being identified, X proves the identity.

*Identification in X* means *an identity was determined inside or within X.*  Something outside of X is proving the identity.

It can be confusing because a picture can both determine an identity, and one can also identify things in it.  It definitely could have been phrased better.

Answer (score 0):

The last sentence means, "The latter three became celebrities after they were identified as the men in the photograph." So, **in** is correct.